# Create multiple text-shadow values using SASS/SCSS

Tags: css, sass

So I want to create a `text-shadow` effect with many different values, something like this:

```
 .drop-shadow{
   text-shadow:
     1px 1px rgba(40,40,40,1)
     2px 2px rgba(40,40,40,.99)
     3px 3px rgba(40,40,40,.98)
     4px 4px rgba(40,40,40,.97)
     ...;
}
```

I have tried using SCSS to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to iterate over the value of a selector. For example, I tried:

```
.drop-shadow{
  @for $i from 1 through 100{
    $num: $i + px;
    $pct: $i / 100;
    $black: 1 - $pct;
    text-shadow: $num $num rgba( 40,40,40,$black );
  }
}
```

But this just returns:

```
.drop-shadow{
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(40,40,40,1);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(40,40,40,.99);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(40,40,40,.98);
  text-shadow: 4px 4px rgba(40,40,40,.97);
  ...;
}
```

Where each subsequent `text-shadow` rule simply overrules the previous one.

Is there any way to loop *inside* of the text-shadow rule?

Comment: Obvious question: have you tried `text-shadow: @for $i from 1 through 100{...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define `variable` out side the `loop` and collect the shadow values on it. Then add the variable as a value of your `text-shadow` property.

```
.drop-shadow{
  $value: ();
  @for $i from 1 through 100{
    $num: $i + px;
    $pct: $i / 100;
    $black: 1 - $pct;
    $theShadow:$num $num rgba( 40,40,40,$black );
    $value: append($value, $theShadow, comma)

  }
  text-shadow: $value;
}
```